# How can I print the hierarchy of the clusters with sklearn or scipy clustering methods?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'm doing some agglomerative clustering tests with the library sklearn.cluster, but I can't print the hierarchy of the classes obtained. I need to be able to obtain the hierarchy, p.e [[1, [3,2]],[5, [[0, 4], 6]]. This mean that "Class 1 has Class 3 as left-child and Class 2 as right-child.

Is it possible to obtain something like this?

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
import numpy as np

json_message = {
    "dataDesc": {
        "data": {
            "coords1": [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
            "coords2": [5.8, 4.0, 1.2, 0.2],
            "coords3": [5.7, 4.4, 1.5, 0.4],
            "coords4": [5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4],
            "coords5": [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.3],
            "coords6": [5.7, 3.8, 1.7, 0.3],
            "coords8": [5.1, 3.8, 1.5, 0.2],
            "coords9": [5.4, 3.4, 1.7, 0.3],
            "coords10": [5.1, 3.7, 1.5, 0.4],
            "coords11": [4.6, 3.6, 1.0, 0.2]
        },
        "expression": "coords"
    },
    "options": {
        "distanceType": "euclidean",
        "linkage": "ward",
        "n_clusters": 4
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_message['dataDesc']['data'], orient='index')

result = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=json_message['options']['n_clusters'],
                                 affinity=json_message['options']['distanceType'],
                                 linkage=json_message['options']['linkage']).fit(df)
print(result.labels_)
```

The output is

> [3 0 0 0 3 1 3 1 3 2]

But what I want is to have the hierarchy of the classes.

I tried to do the same with scipy.hierarchy, but only shows the hierarchy, doesn't have the information to print it.

The code is:

```
items = np.array(list(json_message["dataDesc"]['data'].values()))
hier = hierarchy.linkage(items, 'single')
value = hierarchy.dendrogram(hier)
```

And the output generated:

[image]

The image shows what I really want, but I need the hierarchy in text, not as an image. I saw the documentation, but I didn't get an answer.

Comment: You need to add some code snippets of what you have already tried etc. See the guide on how to get an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use scipy and not sklearn for hierarchical clustering! It is much better. You can derive the hierarchy easily from the 4 column matrix returned by scipy.cluster.hierarchy (just the string formatting will be a minor pain - you probably need to carefully read the manual to understand the matrix).